# Should there be a sandbox for other sites too?

Tags: discussion, sandbox

I personally think we should have sandbox on more sites.

Not sites like Stack Overflow just ones that are necessary.

Comment: You mean on main sites, or meta sites? If main, what you mean by "other", since there's no main site with a sandbox?

Comment: @Shadow Wizard Either main or meta networks

Comment: What would be the benefit of having more sandboxes?

Comment: The terminology that others are trying to point out is that there's only on "network" - the Stack Exchange Network. The entities of that network are "sites". Saying "other networks" implies that you're talking about something outside Stack Exchange.

Comment: @Catija it's clear enough OP means other sites, but not clear what they mean by sandbox.

Comment: If they're basing the question on Puzzling, it's pretty clear to me what they mean, @ShadowWizard   :) They have a pretty active sandbox there. Similar question on puzzling meta : https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6307/37360

Comment: As in on PPCG or puzzling. Here's a link: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges

Comment: This is better asked on whatever site you feel might need this feature in actual practice. Having a nebulous discussion here about what other (unspecified) sites might need will not likely result in any actionable outcome here. This should be asked on the specific meta community you have become concerned about.

Comment: @Catija but it's on their meta site, right? I see no purpose in sandbox on main sites.

Comment: @ShadowWizard main makes no sense, correct.

Comment: This post does not pertain to one site only. What makes you think that?

Comment: @RobertCartaino While I understand your comment, I disagree with your close reason that it pertains to *one* specific site. Why not close it as off-topic with a custom comment?

Comment: @SonicWizard Because it's a question to raise with a specific community as needed, not a network issue that will be decided here globally for everyone. That doesn't mean that multiple communities can't have that conversation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### I'm not so sure

With sites like PPCG and Puzzling.SE, there is a need for a sandbox. On those sites, it is necessary to think about your posts beforehand, as they are planned and meant for thinking about. But many sites on Stack Exchange (like Stack Overflow, Pets, or Physics) are designed for problems to be answered. On Stack Overflow, you will not need to sandbox a question about a Javascript `ReferenceError`, as this is not planned or necessary. Of course, you said only necessary sites, and these already have sandboxes.

Comment: Why would sites need a formatting sandbox just because it's necessary to think about the answers beforehand?

Comment: @DonaldDuck Not all sandboxes are formatting sandboxes.

Answer (score 12):

If you think a specific site could benefit from a Sandbox, propose it on that site's child meta and see what the users of that site think. Many sites already have a sandbox for discussing potential questions or answers or working out formatting.

That said, it's not up to the MSE community to decide this. Only the community can decide for themselves whether it would be useful or not.

Answer (score 4):

If a stack doesn't have a sandbox, it's probably because the users there don't feel that one is needed. If you disagree, you should post on *that particular stack's meta*, proposing the addition of a sandbox, and laying out your case for why it's needed *for that stack*.